# Get a field from an object from a metamodel

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The multiselect method of the CriteriaQuery object takes fields from the meta-model. I have a problem because one of the fields is an object from which I would also like to download the field

```
final CriteriaQuery<...> contentQuery = cb.createQuery(...class);

        contentQuery.multiselect(
                root.get(Entity_.uniqueId)
                root.get(Entity_.user),
                ...
        );
```

the point is that from the `user` field of the entity `Entity` I would like to get the username, but I do not know how to do it. Something like that `root.get(Entity_.user.username)`. Of course, my example does not work. Can you do it somehow?